# Executing sequence of commands from Ritchtextbox through looping

Tags: regex, vb.net, loops

I am currently working on a project that involves sending and receiving data from serialport and tcp/ip.

Whenever I received message from the devices I output it in richtextbox lastline then I process the received message accordingly, all of this are working fine except when the device sends multiple commands in just 1 line.

For example the device is programatically assigned to send 1 command at a time, something like this:

> MSTAT01P0K0S0^
>
> MSTAT02P1K1S1^
>
> MSTAT03P0K0S0^
>
> MSTAT04P1K1S1^

Since I am receiving 1 command at a time I can append it to my richtextbox lastline and easily process it. But sometimes there are cases which prevents the device from sending it 1 command at a time, it will be looked like this

> MSTAT01P0K0S0^
>   MSTAT02P1K1S1^
>   MSTAT03P0K0S0^
>   MSTAT04P1K1S1^

Instead of having 4 lines of code in my richtextbox I now have 1 link with 4 commands. This is my problem.

**Question:** How do I modify my code to process commands from the lastline of richtextbox?

`Note:` I can determine the start and end of commands that I received from the device by indicating `M` as the start and `^` as the end.

I have this code:

```
Dim Sched_Num As String = String.Empty
    Dim KS_Status As String = String.Empty
    Dim SSR_Status As String = String.Empty
    Dim Photocell_Status As String = String.Empty

    Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(events_process, "(M[^\^]+\^)")
    For Each m As Match In matches
        For Each c As Capture In m.Captures
            Dim CSTAT_Cmd As Boolean = events_process Like "MSTAT??P?K?S?^*"
            If CSTAT_Cmd = True Then
                Sched_Num = events_process.Substring(5, 2)
                Photocell_Status = events_process.Substring(8, 1)
                KS_Status = events_process.Substring(10, 1)
                SSR_Status = events_process.Substring(12, 1)
            End If
        Next
        Console.WriteLine(Sched_Num & " " & Photocell_Status & " " & KS_Status & " " & SSR_Status)
    Next
```

And it is working great when it comes to 1 command at a time, the problem is when the device send chunks of command.

If I received message: `MSTAT01P0K0S0^`. It outputs `01 0 0 0` which is correct!

If I received message: `MSTAT01P0K0S0^MSTAT10P1K1S1`. It outputs `01 0 0 0` again. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, when you're inside the inner `For Each`, use the `Value` property from the `Capture` object instead of `events_process` like this:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim events_process = "MSTAT01P0K0S0^ MSTAT02P1K1S1^ MSTAT03P0K0S0^ MSTAT04P1K1S1^"
        Dim Sched_Num As String = String.Empty
        Dim KS_Status As String = String.Empty
        Dim SSR_Status As String = String.Empty
        Dim Photocell_Status As String = String.Empty
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(events_process, "(M[^\^]+\^)")

        For Each m As Match In matches
            For Each c As Capture In m.Captures
                Dim CSTAT_Cmd As Boolean = c.Value Like "MSTAT??P?K?S?^*"
                If CSTAT_Cmd = True Then
                    Sched_Num = c.Value.Substring(5, 2)
                    Photocell_Status = c.Value.Substring(8, 1)
                    KS_Status = c.Value.Substring(10, 1)
                    SSR_Status = c.Value.Substring(12, 1)
                    Console.WriteLine(Sched_Num & " " & Photocell_Status & " " & KS_Status & " " & SSR_Status)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
01 0 0 0
02 1 1 1
03 0 0 0
04 1 1 1
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yr52T1)

Actually the inner `For Each`, isn't needed.  You can just use the outer `For Each` with the `Value` property from the `Match` object

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim events_process = "MSTAT01P0K0S0^ MSTAT02P1K1S1^ MSTAT03P0K0S0^ MSTAT04P1K1S1^"
        Dim Sched_Num As String = String.Empty
        Dim KS_Status As String = String.Empty
        Dim SSR_Status As String = String.Empty
        Dim Photocell_Status As String = String.Empty

        Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(events_process, "(M[^\^]+\^)")
        For Each m As Match In matches
            Dim CSTAT_Cmd As Boolean = m.Value Like "MSTAT??P?K?S?^*"
            If CSTAT_Cmd = True Then
                Sched_Num = m.Value.Substring(5, 2)
                Photocell_Status = m.Value.Substring(8, 1)
                KS_Status = m.Value.Substring(10, 1)
                SSR_Status = m.Value.Substring(12, 1)
                Console.WriteLine(Sched_Num & " " & Photocell_Status & " " & KS_Status & " " & SSR_Status)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
01 0 0 0
02 1 1 1
03 0 0 0
04 1 1 1
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8KgftN)

Comment: You are great, that's what I'm looking for. Thank you so much! You just saved my day :)